# Finding potential function of $\vec F =xy^2 \hat i +y x^2 \hat j$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, physics

> $$\vec F =xy^2 \hat i +y x^2 \hat j$$

My attempt:

$$P=U_{x}=xy^2$$

$$Q=U_{y}=x^2y$$

$$\Longrightarrow U=\int P dx=\frac{x^2}{2}y+C(y)$$

$$ U_{y}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C'(y)=Q=x^2y$$

$$\Longrightarrow \boxed{U=\frac{x^2}{2}y+-\frac{y^2}{2}x^2+C(y)}$$

> Is it correct?

Comment: I believe you'd need to find and then substitute $C(y)$ into $U$. Also, you'd need a constant in your final expression for $U$ as for $U$ to be a potential of $\mathbf{F}$, you'd need that $\mathbf{\nabla} U = \mathbf{F}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a potential function of $\mathbf{\vec F}$ is a function $f$ such that $\mathbf{\vec F} = \vec \nabla f$. We recognize that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = \frac{x^2}{2}-yx^2+C'(y) \neq yx^2$ for any choice of $C(y)$, so your answer is unfortunately incorrect.

There is a small mistake in the third line of your computations. We have $$f(x,y) = \int xy^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 \color{red}{y^2} + C(y).$$ Then, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^2y + C'(y)=yx^2$ so $C'(y) = 0$. It follows that $C(y) = k$ for some constant $k$. Thus, for any $k$, $f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2}x^2 y^2 + k$ is a potential function for $\mathbf{\vec F}$.